# Find largest and smallest value across numerous columns on specific row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL named 'partshistory' as follows:

```
Part        *col1*      *col2*      *col3*
------------------------------------------
AAA1000     1.10        1.15        1.05
AAB1000     1.85        0.50        2.30
AAC1000     20.00       19.95       10.10
```

The column names besides 'Part' are unknown, as these are labelled with the date when the data is added. But this could be on any date.

But given a part number, say 'AAB1000', how can I go about finding both the largest, and smallest values across all the rows for that part?

So the output would be:

0.50 and 2.30.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? But having a table where you don't know the column names is a really strange design

Comment: Fix your data model!  You absolutely should know the names of columns in a table.  You should be adding data in new *rows* not new *columns*.

Comment: Hopefully one that has a GREATEST and LEAST function, and a information schema that can tell you the column names ...

Comment: MySQL, the thing is I have around 86,000 part numbers, so to me it seemed more logical to enter the parts as rows, and create a new column each time a new price list comes along. Otherwise I'll end up with 86,000 columns.

Comment: You need to get this design corrected ASAP. I can't imagine trying to work with such a data model. You need to normalize that table to first normal form because each of those columns is essentially part of a repeating group.

Comment: Thank you for all of your kind attention, I will revise the design of the table to store this in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Combine `MIN()` and `MAX()` with `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()`.

For example:

```
select
  min(least(col1, col2, col3)) as smallest,
  max(greatest(col1, col2, col3)) as biggest
from partshistory
where part = 'AAB1000'
```

Since the table name is `partshistory` I assumed there could be multiple rows for the same part.